# Access jcr:content propeties from page node

Tags: aem, jcr

I have dropdown where the values of options are like `jcr:content/jcr:title`, `jcr:content/jcr:description`, `/jcr:content/par/entry/text` etc. Here the last one is the property of parent, like `jcr:title` is the property of `jcr:content` node & text is the property of entry node, but entry has parent par and par has parent `jcr:content`. I am at the page node and using the below code to fetch such values which doesn't work :

```
        Node n = (Node)nodeIter.next();
        log.info(n.getProperty("/jcr:content/par/entry/text"));
```

Any Idea how to get values in such a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the starting slash from the property path. It makes the path absolute while you are interested in the relative one (as in other examples you've described):

```
n.getProperty("jcr:content/par/entry/text");
```